# getItemAtPosition in recycleview

Tags: android

I want to get the position of the selected folder and get its id... it was working fine in a listview but now i changed to recycleview and i don't know how to get the position of it.

```
lst.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // String folder = lst.getItemAtPosition( lst.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            String folder = (String) lst.getItemAtPosition(i);
            String id = (String) lstMap.get(i);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Vous avez choisis "+ id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            String newReq= new StringBuilder().append(AppConfig.URL_GetFoldersFK).append(id).toString();
            Log.d("Request show",newReq);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BuildingsListActivity.class);
            // Sending value to another activity using intent.
            intent.putExtra("FolderId", newReq);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?  What is lst here? is it the recycler view? if it is, you should know that Recycler View don't have a onItemClickListener(), check my RecylerView example in github https://github.com/MustafizurRahman/RecyclerViewExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `RecyclerView` adapter you should do something like this in the `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    String id = (String) lstMap.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BuildingsListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("FolderId", id);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `getAdapterPosition()` will return the position of the selected view inside your `viewholder`.
- you also can use `position` that passed from `onBindViewHolder(...)` method inside the Adapter